# Mapping module imports in Python for easy refactoring

Tags: python, refactoring, module, python-module

I have a bunch of Python modules I want to clean up, reorganize and refactor (there's some duplicate code, some unused code ...), and I'm wondering if there's a tool to make a map of which module uses which other module.

Ideally, I'd like a map like this:

```
main.py
 -> task_runner.py
  -> task_utils.py
  -> deserialization.py
   -> file_utils.py
 -> server.py
  -> (deserialization.py)
  -> db_access.py

checkup_script.py
re_test.py
main_bkp0.py
unit_tests.py
```

... so that I could tell which files I can start moving around first (file_utils.py, db_access.py), which files are not used by my main.py and so could be deleted, etc. (I'm actually working with around 60 modules)

Writing a script that does this probably wouldn't be *very* complicated (though there are different syntaxes for import to handle), but I'd also expect that I'm not the first one to want to do this (and if someone made a tool for this, it might include other neat features such as telling me which classes and functions are probably not used).

Do you know of any tools (even simple scripts) that assist code reorganization?

Do you know of a more exact term for what I'm trying to do? Code reorganization?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Python's [`modulefinder`](http://docs.python.org/library/modulefinder.html) does this. It is quite easy to write a script that will turn this information into an import graph (which you can render with e.g. [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/)): here's a [clear explanation](http://www.tarind.com/depgraph.html). There's also [`snakefood`](http://furius.ca/snakefood/) which does all the work for you (and using ASTs, too!)

You might want to look into [`pylint`](http://www.logilab.org/857) or [`pychecker`](http://pychecker.sourceforge.net/) for more general maintenance tasks.

Comment: Thanks! I managed to get exactly the map I was looking for by shamelessly stealing the code in the explanation you sent and poking it until it gave me the graph I needed. I also used modulefinder to list the modules I wasn't using (more than half), so I could just nuke'em and not think about them any more.

I also got pylint, but didn't play with it much yet.

Comment: The  clear explanation link (http://www.tarind.com/depgraph.html) is dead.

Answer (score 4):

> Writing a script that does this probably wouldn't be very complicated (though there are different syntaxes for import to handle),

It's trivial.  There's `import` and `from module import`.  Two syntax to handle.

> Do you know of a more exact term for what I'm trying to do? Code reorganization?

Design.  It's called *design*.  Yes, you're refactoring an existing design, but...

**Rule One**

Don't start a design effort with what you have.   If you do, you'll only "nibble around the edges" making small and sometimes inconsequential changes.

**Rule Two**

Start a design effort with what you *should* have had if you'd only been smarter.  Think broadly and clearly about what you're *really* supposed to be doing.  Ignore what you did.

**Rule Three**

Design *from the ground up* (or *de novo* as some folks say) with the correct package and module architecture.

Create a separate project for this.

**Rule Four**

Test First.  Write unit tests for your new architecture.  If you have existing unit tests, copy them into the new project.  Modify the imports to reflect the new architecture and rewrite the tests to express your glorious new simplification.

All the tests fail, because you haven't moved any code.  That's a good thing.

**Rule Five**

Move code into the new structure last.  Stop moving code when the tests pass.

You don't need to analyze imports to do this, BTW.  You're just using `grep` to find modules and classes.  The old imports and the tangled relationships among the old imports doesn't matter, and doesn't need to be analyzed.  You're throwing it away.  You don't need tools smarter than `grep`.

If feel an urge to move code, you must be very disciplined. (1) you must have test(s) which fail and then (2) you can move some code to pass the failing test(s).

Comment: +1. and don't forget `import module.submod as submod` as a variant. It's been growing on me.

Comment: @aaronasterling: Still looks like `r"\s*import\s+.*"` to me.

Comment: Rewriting from scratch is often not practical, and could lead to Duke Nukem Forever syndrome.

Answer (score 2):

[chuckmove](http://github.com/sb98052/chuckmove) is a tool that lets you recursively rewrite imports in your entire source tree to refer to a new location of a module.

```
chuckmove --old sound.utils --new media.sound.utils src
```

...this descends into src, and rewrites statements that import sound.utils to import media.sound.utils instead. It supports the whole range of Python import formats. I.e. `from x import y`, `import x.y.z as w` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Modulefinder may not work with Python 3.5*, but [pydeps](https://github.com/thebjorn/pydeps) worked very well:

Installation:

```
sudo apt install python-pygraphviz
pip install pydeps
```

Then, in the directory where you want to map from,

```
pydeps --max-bacon=0 .
```

..to create a map of maximum depth.

*An issue in Python 3.5 but not 3.6 caused the problems with modulefinder, similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43163201/pyinstaller-syntax-error-yield-inside-async-function-python-3-5-1)