# Pyinstaller Syntax error: 'yield' inside async function (Python 3.5.1)

Tags: pyinstaller

I am trying to use `pyinstaller` to create a single executable to distribute to users without Python installed.

The script is a very simple one and just to test waters I'm using just a few lines of code as "Guinea Pig".

The `Hello World` program - no imports, converts fine.

My Guinea Pig program, which imports `matplotlib.pyplot` and plots a list of values, fails.

The issue is known and documented [here](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2434), although they claim it is fixed, or maybe I can't read correctly.
I think the fix should be available in the "dev version" which should be 3.2.1, and I have installed through `pip install --upgrade pyinstaller`, to no avail.

I keep getting the same syntax error, which occurs when reading the

```
module jinja2\asyncsupport.py
```

Any idea how to work around this? My project is ultra simple and it just involves `matplotlib`, `pandas`, reading a file and plotting some data.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I got the same error.

The reason is Jinja2 added new async function for Python3.6 in version 2.9.

Please see http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/changelog/#version-2-9-6

There are two ways to avoid this error.
Both of these worked for me.

1. Downgrade jinja2

   ```
      # using Anaconda
      conda install jinja2=2.8.1

      # using pip
      pip install jinja2==2.8.1
   ```
2. Install dev version of PyInstaller

   ```
     # install from github
     # Don't run "pip install -U pyinstaller" because the dev version is not released yet
     pip install git+https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller.git

     # check if "PyInstaller (3.3.dev0+g483dfde)" is in the list
     pip list
   ```

Comment: Thanks! Option 1 worked seamlessly. I had tried option 2 already on my own, but I failed as I didn't have `git` installed.